# Angular: I store API response (Observable) in local storage & trying to get back as given code, but getting different format observable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

**Angular: I store API response (Observable) in local storage & trying to get back as given code, but getting different format observable**

My Code Snippet (Part Of Service Method):

```
....
....
if(this.currentProgram!=this.previousProgram){
      this.previousProgram = this.currentProgram;
      let students_stream = this.http.get(url);
      localStorage.setItem("studs_stream", JSON.stringify(students_stream));
      return students_stream;
}else{
      this.studsstream = of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studs_stream")));
      return this.studsstream;
}
....
....
```

In else part.. I am trying to get stored (local storage) API response (Observable) back using "of" operator. Its getting but with different Observable parameters (you can see into attached screenshot). I want same Observable data which I am storing into local storage.

Please suggest me changes to get same Observable data again from local storage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should replace:

```
this.studsstream = of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studs_stream")));
```

With

```
this.studsstream = new Observable(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studs_stream")));
```

Comment: tried.. but getting same issue.. this time I didn't get "value" parameter of 2nd part of screenshot

Comment: Got it...why do you wish to store the observable? @Hemant P

Comment: in project, same observable is used at the most of the place.. and each time its executing if section api call.. which causing to app speed.. I cant replace the script for that much places.. so I am trying to store this api response in local storage to avoid repeating API calls unnecessorily.

Comment: I get it. Is it possible that you could use a service, like a "backend.service.ts" so you could manage api calls in there? I prefer to use a service and handle al responses in there instead of individually calling http on each component. Also is it possible for you to store only the api response object/data instead of the observable itself?

Comment: given code snippet itself is part of service function, which is getting call from multiple components. API response is getting into observable format.